# Unknown column error in create trigger query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

Here is the query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_user_update AFTER INSERT ON tbl_user 
FOR EACH ROW 

INSERT INTO useraccessmap 
SET 
username = NEW.username, 
first_name =  NEW.first_name, 
last_name=NEW.last_name, 
active=NEW.active,
access_method=NEW.access_method, 
name=NEW.name;
```

I'm getting the following error:

> unknown column 'name' in 'NEW'

'name' is a table column, and I have to refer the same term 'name'. Is there any way?

column 'name' is from different table. How to specify the other table here?
Actually 'useraccessmap' is a joined table.

Comment: is `tbl_user` has a column called `name` ?

Comment: Can You Share Your Table

Comment: Can you pls share the create table statement for tbl_user?

Comment: tbl_user doesnt have 'name' column. column 'name' is from different table. How to specify the other table here?
Actually 'useraccessmap' is a joined table.

Comment: I need to update the joined table 'useraccessmap' which is made after joining two tables 'tbl_user' and 'access".
'access' table has column 'name'.

I need to update 'useraccessmap' table whenever a new entry is made in 'tbl_user' table.

Comment: What is a "joined table"?

Comment: I meant I created a new table from two tables using join.

Answer (score -1):

Check Your Columns In Table 
OR Try This One

```
INSERT INTO useraccessmap 
SET 
username = NEW.username, 
first_name =  NEW.first_name, 
last_name=NEW.last_name, 
active=NEW.active,
access_method=NEW.access_method, 
name=NEW.`name`;
```